# Journey Builder, Same contact to enter 2 decision split in one journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

My requirement is to make the contact enter into Iphone decision split and Samsung incase if the contact purchased both the assets.

Here is the scenario, A contact purchases Iphone and Samsung Smartphone on same day; for iphone customers i have to send iphone emails and Samsung customers a samsung email.

If a contact has one asset I have no problem and Journey is working fine. but when a customer has 2 assets (iphone and Samsung) then contact is entering into one decision split and receiving 2 emails from the same (iPhone).

Expectation is he should receive 2 emails (one from iphone and one from Samsung )

Not sure how to overcome this issue.

we are using event based - Email studio audience. DE has 2 rows for the same customer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an entry event with a transaction key, so the rows are identified correctly.

> Transaction keys combine an ID value that Journey Builder generates and a unique contact attribute value to create a wholly unique identifier. This unique identifier is observed by all contact filters in the journey, including filters in the entry event and decision split activities. This prevents contacts in the journey from following the unintended path when their ContactID still matches current entry or decision split criteria due to a previous transaction.
>
> The contact attributes available for creating a transaction key are ContactID and ContactKey. Transaction keys are commonly used when a journey's entry event is fired via API.

I created an example for such a custom entry event that makes use of transaction keys on my github account (MIT licensed): [Custom Event with Transaction Key](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-customevent-with-transactionkey)

**Further documentation can be found here:**

- [Create Custom Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-events.htm)
- [Create Unique Journey Results using Transaction Keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/transaction-key.htm)
- [Journey Settings -> Transaction key](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_settings/)

Comment: You are welcome! If my input helped, please mark my answer as accepted, so others can easily see this solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: In the last few days, a journey that I used to demostrate this issue, just started working, like if journey builder supported this without the need of a custom transaction key. Do you know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one data extension with a field that has a value of either "iphone" or "samsung" in a "Phone purchased" field, you could create two separate journeys that send the emails.

You would get 3 cases:

1. iphone buyer enters the iphone journey
2. samsung buyer enters the samsung journey
3. buyers of both iphones or samsung phones would enter both journeys.

---

Don't want to have multiple journeys?

Transform the data so that you have a data extension with boolean fields for both iphone and samsung phone purchases.

You could then be able to create a third path in the decision split and set multiple condition in the assignment rules.

The decision split would then split the users as follows:

1. iphone purchase = true, samsung purchase = false
2. iphone purchase = false, samsung purchase = true
3. iphone purchase = true, samsung purchase = true

Comment: Rufenstein, thanks for the suggestion. but 3rd option should be receiving two emails, how to send different emails was the problem.

Comment: That's pretty simple.

By creating those 3 splits, you would have 3 paths for potential customers. Just place 2 email blocks on the same path and you send 2 messages to users on this path.